# How do I add an interface to a package?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Suppose I have the following interface deceleration :

```
public interface classListener<classEvent> {

    void classMethod1(classEvent x);
    void classMethod2(classEvent y);
    void classMethod3(classEvent z);
}
```

and suppose I want to add this interface to *whatever.something* package.

What should i do ?

Comment: Just create the interface withing the package.

Comment: Not sure where are you confusing? It's a quite obvious way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `package` statement at the top of the file:

```
package your.package.name;

public interface classListener<classEvent> {

    void classMethod1(classEvent x);
    void classMethod2(classEvent y);
    void classMethod3(classEvent z);
}
```

> suppose I want to add this interface to *java.something* package

You cannot add to the `java.` packages. That's just for the JDK (currently controlled by Oracle since they acquired Sun). It'll compile, but when you try to use it you'll get a `SecurityException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:479)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:625)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: UsePackage.  Program will exit.
```

My code that gave me that error:

In `~/temp/java/util/AddPackage.java`:

```
package java.util;

public interface AddPackage {
    void doSomething();
}
```

In `~/temp/UsePackage.java`:

```
import java.util.AddPackage;

class UsePackage implements AddPackage {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new UsePackage().doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Commands:

```
~/temp$ javac java/util/AddPackage.java
~/temp$ javac UsePackage.java
~/temp$ java UsePackage
```

...whereupon the error occured. Using Oracle's (Sun's) JVM.

Comment: Think packages names and classes names shouldn't conflict and that's all

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue: The `java.*` packages are defined by, and reserved for, the JDK -- currently controlled by Oracle.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets: I tried it and got the exception shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes , I know that I can't add to java. packages . I meant any package. fixed. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The package decl creates a namespace for the content below. Just add a package decl as first line in your interface file.

package org.whatever.foo

public interface ....